# Pandas series/df update with set_index()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Considering the below dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["11","1", "2"], ["12","1", "2"], ["13","3", "4"]],
                 columns=["ix","a", "b"])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["22","8", "9"], ["12","10", "11"], ["23","12", "13"]],
                     columns=["ix","c", "b"])

df                     df1
    ix  a   b        ix  c   b
0   11  1   2     0  22  8   9
1   12  1   2     1  12  10  11
2   13  3   4     2  23  12  13
```

if we execute `df.update(df1)` , this will update the entire column `ix` & `b` of dataframe -`df` since the index number for both dataframes are same.

However, I was trying to set the `ix` column as index for both the dataframes and trying to update the first one as shown below:

```
df_new = df.set_index('ix').rename_axis(None).update(df1.set_index('ix').rename_axis(None))
```

However, this does not return anything.

I was expecting this to return a dataframe with column `b` updated for `df` where `ix` of `df1` and `df` matches. Something like:

```
    a   b
11  1   2
12  1   11
13  3   4
```

Am I missing something here? Is `df.update()` is not meant for executing in a copy of a dataframe? Can anyone please explain me why is this happening.

Comment: Yes, `update` is an in-place operation that returns nothing. You will need to assign the set_index result before calling update, and then reset_index after.

Comment: `df.set_index('ix').rename_axis(None)` returns a copy, to which you call `update`. `update` returns None, and the copy, having been updated, no longer has any references and is eventually garbage collected.

Comment: Not unless you have a reference to the copy.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want to update the original? In that case, just make a copy: `df_copy = df.set_index('ix'); df_copy.update(df1.set_index('ix'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) modifies the calling DataFrame in-place. From the docs:

> Modify in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame.
>
> Aligns on indices. There is no return value.

So, your only option is to set the index as a separate step beforehand.

```
df.set_index('ix', inplace=True)
df.update(df1.set_index('ix'))
df.reset_index()

   ix  a   b
0  11  1   2
1  12  1  11
2  13  3   4
```

---

If you are trying to avoid modifying the original, this is always another option:

```
df_copy = df.set_index('ix')
df_copy.update(df1.set_index('ix'))
df_copy

    a   b
ix       
11  1   2
12  1  11
13  3   4
```